# How to show List with list of classes in Devexpress Grid?

Tags: master-detail, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have small isue with DevExpress GridControl. I need to show a Class with list of classes in grid in specjal way:

For now i have a class::

```
public class Tabs
{
    public string ModName { get; set; }

    public List<SingleTab> Tab = new List<SingleTab>();

}

public class SingleTab
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Space { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Buf { get; set; }

}
```

And with use of Devexpress Grid i wanted to show it in specjal way like:

1. I want to make a view with only 1 column that will be a ModName Value. And When using that '+' function in grid then i will have secound grid with SingleTab Values.

Like:

Row 1: ModName1 [+]

```
Columns: Name  / Space  / Address  / Buf
         Val1  / Val1   /  Val1    / Val1
         Val2  / Val2   /  Val2    / Val2
         Val3  / Val3   /  Val3    / Val3
```

For now i have a list with values but when i try to make these list as the Datasource of GridControl only the first Column ModName is visible.

What can i do to make the list params visible underneath the Row with ModName?

I tryed reading some issues about Master-details from Devexpress forum but i cant find any good exampple to my problem.